# ASP.NET MVC4 with ASPX Render Engine: Fill src attribute dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Presenting a list of items I would like to change the image of the items base on a Type property.
This is the code:

```
<img src="<%if (item.VolumeType == 1)
                                Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/DVDDisk.png"));
                            else
                                Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/harddisk.png")); %>" height="32" width="32" />
```

But any image is displayed because inspecting the html I find:

```
<img src="" height="32" width="32">
```

What's wrong? 
I have not yet understood whether it is valid to use ASPX with MVC engine or if it is an incorrect practice and is best Razor.

Thank you!

Comment: try `<img src="@(item.VolumeType == 1 
? Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/DVDDisk.png")) 
: Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/harddisk.png")))" height="32" width="32">`

Comment: @adiga No Razor here :)

Comment: @AntonGogolev Didn't read the question properly. Just saw the tags and assumed it was a case of missing () brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a conditional operator (`?:`) rather than an inline `if` and an inline expression block (`<%=`) rather than an inline code block (`<%`). The following should do what you are after:

```
<img src="<%= item.VolumeType == 1 ?
    Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/DVDDisk.png")) :
    Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/harddisk.png")) %>" height="32" width="32" />
```

For what it's worth, you could simplify the above by removing the `string.Format` calls (as they aren't required) or making use of the `string.Format` to ouptu the file name which removes the duplicate `Url.Content` call:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content(String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", item.VolumeType == 1 ? "DVDDisk" : "harddisk")) %>" height="32" width="32" />
```